# need example for Robot framework xpath to find an XMLelement value when the response contains recurring elements

Tags: python, xml, xpath, robotframework

I am using RF for the first time because it got recommended by others and I was told Python experience was not necessary. Up till now it went "smoothly" but am currently stuck on the following issue. I am testing with IBM's MDM transactions.

I have a situation where I need to retrieve a specific value for further tests, but within the response you have a recurring element.

For example:

```
<TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>
    <AdminContEquivIdPK>443149752876966203</AdminContEquivIdPK>
    <PartyId>445849752876959403</PartyId>
    <AdminPartyId>13022017010</AdminPartyId>
    <AdminSystemType>1</AdminSystemType>
</TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>
<TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>
    <AdminContEquivIdPK>441549752876967603</AdminContEquivIdPK>
    <PartyId>445849752876959403</PartyId>
    <AdminPartyId>f205c1d7-ed84-4852-8d1d-8fcd092af282</AdminPartyId>
    <AdminSystemType>36</AdminSystemType>
    </TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>
```

I need to retrieve the following value from the response: `<AdminPartyId>13022017010</AdminPartyId>`

But Robot Frameworks XML library complains when using XPath because it finds 2 elements of the same name with the `Get Element` Text command.

Is it possible to retrieve the aforementioned value by adding a second value to identify it? For instance, by using `<AdminSystemType>` as a second identifier. If so, how would I need to do it?

Variables:

```
${XmlFilePath} Resources/TransactionXML/addPerson.xml 
${XmlResponsePath} Resources/TransactionXML/addpersonResponse.xml
```

Get Element Text:

```
source=${XmlResponsePath} xpath=.//TCRMPersonBObj/AdminPartyId.
```

I keep looking but the examples I find all refer to attributes which are not applicable in this situation.

Comment: Whats the full robot command you are using? What are you using which isn't working (post your Xpath you are using)

Comment: and Get Element Text  source=${XmlResponsePath}  xpath=.//TCRMPersonBObj/AdminPartyId.  These are the variables I use*** Variables ***
${XmlFilePath}    Resources/TransactionXML/addPerson.xml
${XmlResponsePath}    Resources/TransactionXML/addpersonResponse.xml

Comment: please don't put code in the comment section. You can [edit] your question to include additional information.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example your xpath for the first item will be: `//TCRMAdminContEquivBObj[1]/AdminPartyId`. However, unless it is your testing strategy to always pick the first one, then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a lead and worked out a working setup:

```
 *** Test Cases ***
Read XML Response values from TCRMAdminContEquivBObj
    [Tags]    GetElementsFromTransaction
    ${xml}  Parse Xml   ${XmlResponsePath}
    @{getxml}  Get Elements    ${xml}   .//TCRMAdminContEquivBObj
    Log To Console  ------results----- @{getxml}
    ${state}    Set Variable    NOT FOUND
    ${element3}  Set Variable    NOT FOUND
    : FOR    ${mainelement}    IN    @{getxml}
    \    Log To Console  ------results----- ${mainelement}
    \    ${element1}    Get Element Text    ${mainelement}    AdminPartyId
    \    ${element2}    Get Element Text    ${mainelement}    AdminSystemType
    \    ${element3}    Set Variable If    '${element2}'=='36'    ${element1}    ${state}
    \    Exit For Loop If    '${element3}'!= '${state}'
    #Should Not Be Equal    ${element3}    NOT FOUND    Did not find state    
    Log To Console  ${element3}
```

it may not be neat but seems to work :)